# Flutter - Multiple icons changed colors each icon

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I have 4 icons in bottom bar in my app, I need change color of icon from grey to white, I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185357/how-to-change-icon-color-immediately-after-pressed-in-flutter), but when I'm pressing any icon all icons changed color at the same time, I need when press for example (Home) icon just press (Home) icon.

**How can I do that??**

**And How can I set the home icon always first page without pressing?? (I mean when user open the application show to him home page(white icon)).**

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  _HomePageState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  bool isPressed = false;

  _pressed() {
  var newVal = true;
  if(isPressed) {
    newVal = false;
  } else {
    newVal = true;
  }

  setState((){
  isPressed = newVal;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(

    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Image.asset('assets/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.grey[900],
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.info), color: isPressed ? Colors.white:Colors.grey[600], iconSize: 30, onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _pressed();
          });
        }),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.local_mall), color: isPressed ? Colors.white:Colors.grey[600], iconSize: 30, onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _pressed();
          });
        }),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark), color: isPressed ? Colors.white:Colors.grey[600], iconSize: 30, onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _pressed();
          });
        }),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), color: isPressed ? Colors.white:Colors.grey[600], iconSize: 30, onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _pressed();
          });
        }),
      ],
    ),
  ),

);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this!! really its best trick for toggle icon color

```
   IconButton( icon:  ImageIcon(AssetImage("images/edit.png",) ,size: 30,),
                            disabledColor: Color.fromRGBO(32, 127, 195, 1),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            onPressed: a == 1
                                ? null
                                : () => setState(() => a = 1)),
 IconButton( icon:   ImageIcon(AssetImage("images/notify.png",) ,size: 30,),
                            disabledColor: Color.fromRGBO(32, 127, 195, 1),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            onPressed: a == 2
                                ? null
                                : () => setState(() {
                                      a = 2;
                                      dateTemp = '';
                                    })),
```

Comment: (a) is it integer variable??

Comment: You can check full code here                                                                   https://github.com/hardik584/Flutter-lunchbox/blob/master/developer1996.dart

Comment: have you get your solution?

Comment: Yes! @HardikKumbhani

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same bool variable for each button. Try using integer index (1-4 for each button, and each button press is setting state with the integer set to it's index) and then check which index is pressed when defining color.

Comment: I'm a beginner in flutter

Comment: you can check full code here https://github.com/hardik584/Flutter-lunchbox/blob/master/developer1996.dart